# How do I add a live tile to Windows 8.1 from an RSS feed?

Tags: windows-8.1, rss, feed, live-tiles

How can I create a live tile in Windows8.1 using content from an RSS feed?

For example, if I have an RSS feed http://example.com/feed.xml how can I add this content to a live tile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a look at Scott Hanselman's article:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakeAWindows81PinnedLiveTileForYOURWebsiteInMinutes.aspx

He references a site named [build my pinned site](http://www.buildmypinnedsite.com)

Note: I believe this solution depends on Internet Explorer to work.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.